# Unable to extract python 2.7.x tar file

Tags: python, python-2.7, rhel6

I'm new to linux and python.  I wanted to install the latest version of python but after I downloaded the tar file from: www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.x(I've tried 3 different versions), I'm unable to extract the files. 
[image: I'm getting the following]

I'm using RHEL server release 6.5

What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: you're new to screenshots as well?

Comment: sorry,  but I don't understand.  Do you want some more images?

Comment: no, no, We'd need a clean copy/paste of the command & error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

you can extract tar file with the command

```
>> tar xvzf filename.tar.gz
```

And i recommend you to install the latest version of python with Linux Package Managers

using **su** to change to the root user ID, use **subscription-managerto** verify that you have access to Red Hat Software Repositories.

```
 $ su -
 >> subscription-manager repos --list-enable d
 >> yum update

 $ su -
 >> yum list installed python\*
 >> yum install python
 >> yum list available python\*
```

as described on https://developers.redhat.com/articles/using-native-python-rhel-6-or-rhel-7/

Comment: that seems unrelated to OP problem we don't know the root cause of.